# Parse Query for objects created within current month

Tags: parse-platform

I need to extract all objects created within the current month.

so what I have done thus far is:

```
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm dd, yyyy");
        String date = df.format(new Date());
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("beer_rating");
        query.whereEqualTo("userId", userId);
        query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", date);
        query.countInBackground(new CountCallback(){...
```

this is returning zero me...I know this isn't correct as logically it would only count what was created today...would anyone have any input on this? how to count all objects created within the current month?

Comment: There is a typo in your SimpleDateFormat pattern? ...becouse if not..the month is M (uppercase), m lowercase are minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar.getInstance().set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

will adjust the date to the first of the current month.

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
Date date = calendar.getTime();

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("beer_rating");
query.whereEqualTo("userId", userId);
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", date);
query.countInBackground(new CountCallback(){...
```

Comment: thanks for the helpful response..  Date date = Calendar.getInstance().set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1).getTime(); is throwing up issues.  Calendar.getInstance().set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);is fine but when setting Date date to it and appending .getTime() at the end there is an error...it's a good starting point for me though..thanks

Comment: What issues? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()

Comment: The issue is 'cannot resolve getTime()'.  If I have Calendar.getInstance().getTime() there is no problem.  it's the et(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)that doesn't allow for the method getTime()

Comment: Of course. Cannot combine set and get. I'll modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @Handsomeguy to pointing in the right direction I made the following changes and it works like a charm...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

so big thanks to the input of @Handsomeguy!